# uinput seems to break while sending inputs in quick succession

Tags: c, linux, uinput

I have been trying to use the uinput kernel module to send mouseclicks in quick succession to other programs.

This works fine if the delay between the clicks is **25ms** or greater but it breaks if it is lower.
When it breaks I can see the events with `evtest` but not with `xinput`. Only the first event seems to work normally. (I guess the later events must be somehow lost between those two? Maybe there is a limit that I have missed?)

I have made a small example that reproduces this behaviour. (Most of it is taken from the  [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.15/input/uinput.html))

```
#include <linux/uinput.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define TIME_BETWEEN_CLICKS (25000) // in µs

void emit(int fd, int type, int code, int val)
{
    struct input_event ie;
    ie.type = type;
    ie.code = code;
    ie.value = val;
    ie.time.tv_sec = 0;
    ie.time.tv_usec = 0;
    write(fd, &ie, sizeof(ie));
}

int main(void)
{
    struct uinput_setup usetup;
    int i = 50;
    int fd = open("/dev/uinput", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);

    ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_KEY);
    ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_LEFT);

    memset(&usetup, 0, sizeof(usetup));
    usetup.id.bustype = BUS_USB;
    usetup.id.vendor = 0x1234; /* sample vendor */
    usetup.id.product = 0x5678; /* sample product */
    strcpy(usetup.name, "Example device");

    ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_SETUP, &usetup);
    ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_CREATE);

    sleep(2);

    while (i--) {
        emit(fd, EV_KEY, BTN_LEFT, 1);
        emit(fd, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);
        emit(fd, EV_KEY, BTN_LEFT, 0);
        emit(fd, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);
        usleep(TIME_BETWEEN_CLICKS);
    }
    sleep(1);

    ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_DESTROY);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/mooz/xkeysnail/issues/150 Might be seeing the same issue here, not sure yet.  Did you ever find an answer/solution?

Comment: Just read again... if the events come thru to evdev, then there is no issue with uinput - it's working... something higher up is dropping the events, so your question is misworded.